# Ender 3 V2 USB connection powers screen, but isn't detected by PC or Pi

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, octoprint, usb

I am trying to add an Octopi to my Ender 3 V2 but the Pi cannot detect the printer at all. So I try to connect to Windows and same result. The display turns on and is functional, but when checking device manager there is nothing to be found. I am using the 2.0.7 Marlin firmware on the machine and have tried about 6 different USB cables/other ports.

Comment: Did you install the CH340/1 device drivers on Windows? Note that not all ports may work, my previous computer only allowed connection over the usb ports at the back.

Comment: I just tried all the ports on the back one by one with device manager open and there was no change. I have the CH340 drivers installed, but not the FTDI drivers since device manager doesn't pick it up in the first place.

Comment: What board is it exactly? Uploading the firmware worked fine?

Comment: Is the printer switched on?

Comment: I have the 4.2.2 board, no issues with changing firmwares. I've tried with the power supply on and off, neither make a difference.

Comment: Additionally, running `dmesg` on the Pi doesn't show anything nor does `lsusb`

Comment: Are you sure that when you say "powers screen" you are doing this right? The PI will supply power through a typical USB cable. When the Ender 3 is turned off, the power from the PI will power up the printer's control board even if the printer is turned off. If it is turned off, all bets are off as to what will and won't work. Certainly it won't print, but even the main board may be underpowered if only being supplied by the PI.

Answer (score 2):

After trying about 10 USB cables I finally found one that would work with the Ender and Pi. Specifically, it was my Logitech MX Ergo USB cable.